# Tesseract is slow on Tomcat

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, servlets, tesseract

I write a servlet that use Tesseract for do the OCR. I run all on a Tomcat WebServer
If I test the servlet running Tomcat by Eclipse all work fine. 

If I start Tomcat by console Tesseract is a lot slower instead of I start Tomcat by Eclipse.

How is it possible? Is there any solution to increase speed execution of that?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{   
    int numeroTotalaAree = 0;


    Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
    tesseract.setDatapath(getServletContext().getRealPath("./"));
    tesseract.setLanguage("ita+eng");

    ArrayList<Area> aree = new ArrayList<Area>();

    try 
    {
        String content = "";
        int numeroPagine = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("numeroPagine"));
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroPagine; i++) 
        {
            if(request.getParameter("numeroAree" + i) != null)
            {
                int numeroAree = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("numeroAree" + i));
                if(request.getParameter("x_" + i + "_0") != null)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < numeroAree; j++) 
                    {
                        numeroTotalaAree ++;


                        if((Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("originalHieght")) + Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("x_" + i + "_" + j))) < Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("height_" + i + "_" + j)))
                        {
                            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("x_" + i + "_" + j)), Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("y_" + i + "_" + j)), Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("width_" + i + "_" + j)), Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("height_" + i + "_" + j)) - 2);
                            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("temp/temp-" + i + ".png")));


                            ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bufferedImage.getSubimage((int)r.getX(), (int)r.getY(), (int)r.getWidth(), (int)r.getHeight()), getServletContext().getRealPath("temp/temp.png"), 300);
                            File temp = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("./temp/temp.png"));


                            content = tesseract.doOCR(ImageIO.read(temp)) + "\n";
                            aree.add(new Area(i, j, "Area_" + i + "_" + j, content));

                            temp.delete();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("x_" + i + "_" + j)), Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("y_" + i + "_" + j)), Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("width_" + i + "_" + j)), Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("height_" + i + "_" + j)));
                            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("temp/temp-" + i + ".png")));

                            ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bufferedImage.getSubimage((int)r.getX(), (int)r.getY(), (int)r.getWidth(), (int)r.getHeight()), getServletContext().getRealPath("temp/temp.png"), 300);
                            File temp = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("./temp/temp.png"));


                            content = tesseract.doOCR(ImageIO.read(temp)) + "\n";
                            aree.add(new Area(i, j, "Area_" + i + "_" + j, content));

                            temp.delete();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        request.setAttribute("numeroTotaleAree", numeroTotalaAree);
        request.setAttribute("aree", aree);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Comment: You can use the overloaded `doOCR(BufferedImage bi, Rectangle rect)` method, elmininating the extra file I/O operations.

Comment: @nguyenq I use this method before and all were more slower.